# restarting a single instance application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, clickonce

Is there any way of restarting a single instance application, which is deployed via clickonce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Application.Restart()
```

This will restart a WinForms ClickOnce application.

Comment: I have already tried this solution but the app crashes after the "restart". I don't know if it has something to do with the single instance option.

Comment: Can you give us some details as to how/why it crashes?

Comment: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception 

{"An unexpected error has occurred because an operating system resource required for single instance startup cannot be acquired."}